# Android time is reset after reboot

Tags: android, datetime

I have problem with using `System.currentTimeMillis()` in some devices (especially the emulators with API 25, 26, and I think there will be some other real devices). My case is:

1.Before change time, I turned off both setting options **Automatic date & time** and **Automatic time zone**, I changed from `10h20 AM` to `11h20 AM` => The time is successfully changed. and `System.currentTimeMillis()` give the correct changed time `11h20m AM`.

2. I reboot my device, the time is auto reset to `10h20m AM` and also, `System.currentTimeMillis()` give me the `10h20m AM`, not the changed time at step 1.

So, Any idea to detect whether an android device has "reset time" problem after rebooted or not?

Comment: *I think there will be some other real devices* - why

Comment: @TimCastelijns  Currently, 100% reproduced with emulators 25, 26. But, rarely users have problem with my related time logic. So, I just guessed that.

Answer (score 0):

create a BroadcastReceiver after boot complete and use this

Create an intent filter :

```
     static {
        s_intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
        s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED);
        s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED);
        s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
    }
```

and a broadcast receiver:

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver m_timeChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIME_CHANGED) ||
                action.equals(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED))
            {
                doWorkSon();
            }
        }
    };
```

register the receiver:

```
     public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerReceiver(m_timeChangedReceiver, s_intentFilter);     
    }
```

and unregister it:

```
     public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(m_timeChangedReceiver);     
    }
```

Comment: @ahamad nemati I now you said, but the main problem is the changed time before reboot is reset after rebooted.